# Postgres select into temp table with fucntion

Tags: postgresql

In Postgres, you can select into a temporary table, is it possible to select into temporary table using a function, sucha as

`Select * into temporary table myTempTable from someFucntionThatReturnsATable(1);`

Thanks!

Comment: What happens when you try that?

Comment: Note that the standard `create table .. as select ...` is preferred over the proprietary `select ... into ...`

Comment: @GMB Thanks! It works. I'm writing a fucntion in datagrip and it is giving me syntax errors in the editor. I saw nothing in the doc about selecting into a temp table with a fucntion, so I thought it was wishful thinking. Thanks!

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thanks! I'll keep that in mind.

Comment: @GMB It seems as though the statement can work on it's own, but not in a function. It works if I just execute the one line, but if I add that line into a fucntion, the function will not compile.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name The create table ... as select  works in a function, so I will be using that! Thanks again!